# How can I logically AND two selection conditions in ps?

Tags: ps

I am simulating the default behavior of `ps` without arguments:

- One selection condition is to find processes with controlling terminal being the same as the one of the current shell.
- The other selection condition is to find processes with euid as the current user.

So I need to logically AND the selections by user and terminal.

```
$ ps  -u t -t /dev/pts/4 -o pid,tname,time,ucmd   
$ ps  -u t -t pts/4 -o pid,tname,time,ucmd   
$ ps  -u t -t /dev/tty -o pid,tname,time,ucmd
```

I know the controlling terminal of the current shell is `/dev/pts/4`.
But all give me processes with other controlling terminals and without controlling terminals.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Process selection is cumulative with `-u` and `-t`: you’re selecting all processes running as user `t`, and, on top of those, all processes with controlling terminal `/dev/pts/4` or `/dev/tty`. To see the processes with a given controlling terminal, use `-t` on its own:

```
ps -t pts/4 -o pid,tname,time,ucmd
```

As [specified by POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/ps.html), process selection options are additive:

> With the exception of **-f**, **-l**, **-n** *namelist*, and **-o** *format*, all of the options shown are used to select processes. If any are specified, the default list shall be ignored and *ps* shall select the processes represented by the inclusive OR of all the selection-criteria options.

To combine criteria, only listing processes which match all of them, you can use `pgrep`:

```
ps -p $(pgrep -d, -u t -t pts/4) -o pid,tname,time,ucmd
```

Comment: Thanks. Do the  individual `pgrep`'s options for selecting processes also work without change for `ps`?

Comment: Yes, individually, at least for `-g`, `-G`, `-s`, `-t`, `-u`, and `-U`.

Comment: I guess`ps` and `pgrep` might be created deliberately to behave opposite to each other, instead of each having both AND and OR features. So we will have to use both together sometimes. I don't know what good that can bring.